# How to make pair, from list<int> into map

Tags: c++

I call a function 'createP' in a loop. In every call, I send list as:  'list l', `id` (integer) and an `index` (integer). After calling `createP`, I increment an index by 1.

In `createP` function: I have loop equals the number if items in `list<int> l`

```
for (list<int>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
```

In this loop I do:

```
   comk[index].push_back(*it);
```

where `comk` is a map as `std::map <int, vector <int>> comk;`

In the end, I got:

```
 comk[0]= (0, list of items)
 comk[1]= (1, list of items)
```

and so on. e.g.

```
 comk[0]= (0, (1,2,7))
 comk[1]= (1, (3,8))
```

and so on.

Instead, I want to create `comk` like:

```
 comk[indx]=(list of pairs, the value of these pairs )
```

where each pair contains: (id, one item from the list): let say id =3, then

```
 comk[0]=( ((3,1), (3,2), (3,7)), the `value` of these pairs )
```

the value of these pairs, = the sum of the values of each pair.

I can get the values of these pair from another map, `Mymap`:

```
((1,3), 3)
((2,3), 1)
((3,7), 7)
((4,2), 2)
((8,1), 1)
```

the order of pairs (first entry, second entry) is not important

at the end, I want to get this results:

```
comk[0]=( ((3,1), (3,2), (3,7)), 11 )
comk[1]=( ((1,3), (1,8)), 4)
```

I try to define compk like:

```
std::map< vector< pair< int, int> >, int> comk; 

++Kcom[std::make_pair(first, *it)];
```

beside the syntax error in:

```
++Kcom[std::make_pair(first, *it)];
```

I don't know how to get the values of pairs from `Mymap`

Comment: Try simply `map< pair< int, int>, int>`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this one, but it didn't give me what I want. it didn't not give me: comk[0]=( ((3,1), (3,2), (3,7)), the **value** of these pairs ), instead, it gave me that: comk[0]= (3,1), comk[1]=(3,2), comk[2]= (3,7)

Comment: `map<int, vector<pair<int, int> >`

Comment: I tried this one, which gives me the pairs that I want, in this form:  comk[0]=(0,  (3,1), (3,2), (3,7) ), and comk[1]=(1,  (1,3), (1,8) ), but not : comk[0]=( ((3,1), (3,2), (3,7)), the value of these pairs ) which is comk[0]=( ((3,1), (3,2), (3,7)), 11 ), and comk[1]=( ((1,3), (1,8)),  4). I know one solution to have new map for  the pairs in **comk**, and their values in **Mymap** which is cost more time. i wish if there is away to fast these steps since I have very large data. thank so much for the help

Comment: Are you looking for `comk.insert(std::make_pair(thing 1,thing2));` ?

Comment: Yes, where `thing1` is vector of pairs, and `thing2` is the total (sum) values of all pairs, which exist in another map, namely  `Mymap`as it described above. I don't know how to search for the pairs in `comk` inside `Mymap` and take their values from `Mymap`

Comment: Now, the pairs in `comk` are keys, while the pairs in `Mymap` are values.  I wrote code to search for the pairs in `comk` inside `Mymap`, and take their values from `Mymap`, but I couldn't make it !. this is my try: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c500dcec68e3916

Comment: Can you try re-arranging your question - what exactly do you want to get? this is an algorithmic question and without us understanding what you seek, it will be hard to give you a clear answer